# How to "glue" elements to resizable image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have image with `width: 100%; height: auto;` and on this image are other elements with `position: absolute; left: x; top: x;` (it's a game).

When I was resizing the page, elements weren't moving (it was messing up), so I wrote this:

```
// on start
var img = document.getElementById('world_image'); 

startImageSize.w = img.clientWidth;
startImageSize.h = img.clientHeight;
actImageSize.w = startImageSize.w;
actImageSize.h = startImageSize.h;

// on resize

var img = document.getElementById('world_image'); 

actImageSize.w = img.clientWidth;
actImageSize.h = img.clientHeight;

// update (each tick)

$("#cr_" + this.ID).animate({
    "left" : (this.x - ((startImageSize.w - actImageSize.w) / 2)) + "px",
    "top" : (this.y - ((startImageSize.h - actImageSize.h) / 2)) + "px"
}, speed);
```

But it's not working corretly, here is short GIF representing what is happening:

[image]

A "red point" is moving faster than it shoud be.

// EDDIT! JSFiddle with whole project https://jsfiddle.net/BrunonDEV/18mqyd8r/1/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Basically you should not animate :)

Comment: can you add a link to a jsfiddle / codepen example?

Comment: Using css instead of animate doesn't change anything @hughes sure, I will upload whole project in a while

Comment: JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/BrunonDEV/18mqyd8r/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't try to reposition those in JS - it's slow, makes resizing janky, and chews the javascript cycles you'll need for actually running your game, and it's not necessary anyway. Why not just set your dot's position in %, like this:

```css
.map {
  background: #68B1FF url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5e/BlankMap-World-Sovereign_Nations.svg') center top no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 51.2%; /* The original map image is 1104 x 566px. This is the aspect ratio as a percentage of height to width */
  width: 100%;
}

.marker {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1vw; /* These allow the markers to scale with the map */
  height: 1vw;
  background: red;
  min-height: 8px;
  max-height: 16px;
  min-width: 8px;
  max-width: 16px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <div class="marker" style="top: 20%; left: 33%;"></div>
</div>
```

One of the important pieces here is [fixed aspect ratio boxes in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) - if you set height to 0, and padding-top (or bottom) to a percentage, the padding height is calculated as a percentage of the *width*, not the height as you might expect.

For bonus points, you should use an SVG map image - then it'll scale cleanly, too.